# Cannot pass function of type '(String) async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I have created simple async function to fetch all records from cloudkit for a given types:

```
func fetchAllOf(
    types: [String],
    handler: ProgressHandler?,
    completion: ErrorHandler?
) async {
    var newTypes = types
    var allRecords = [CKRecord]()
    newTypes.forEach { type in
        await fetchAllOf(type: type, handler: handler) { records, error in
            guard let error = error else {
                allRecords += records
                return
            }
            completion?(error)
        }
    }
}
```

where:

```
private func fetchAllOf(
    type: String,
    predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true),
    handler: ProgressHandler?,
    completion: RecordsErrorHandler?
) async {
}
```

Why do I have an error there?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/async-and-concurrent-forEach-and-map/) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mix (custom) completion handlers with `async/await`.

The error occurs because a regular `forEach` closure is not `async` and doesn't have a return value.

Make `fetchAllOf(type:handler:)` – the singular one – also async (and `throws`) and write something like

```
func fetchAllOf(
    types: [String],
    handler: ProgressHandler?) async throws -> [CKRecord] {
        var allRecords = [CKRecord]()
        for aType in types {
            let records = try await fetchAllOf(type: aType, handler: handler)
            allRecords += records
        }
        return allRecords
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are right. Thank you. I will try to implement this now. I am curious if I can make it working like you said.

Comment: There are `async` versions of all relevant CloudKit APIs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75475683/2725435, I almost did it, without one low level part of the code. I cannot rewrite everything now. So I have to somewhere mix the two ot them... for now. COuld you help me with this?